# media.getDuration().toSeconds() returning 0 on some songs

Tags: java, javafx-2, jmf

I've written the following piece of code

```
Media hit = new Media(dir); 
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(hit);
runMedia run = new runMedia(player);
Ui.changeGuiTitle("Now playing: "+getLastBitFromUrl(dirUnencoded.toString()));
Ui.updateInitialTime(getTime(hit.getDuration().toSeconds()));
```

getTime method:

```
System.out.println(time);
System.out.println(Math.round(time));
double seconds = Math.round(time);
double modulo = seconds % 60;
double hours = (seconds - modulo) / 3600;
double minutes = hours / 60;
String Time = "";

if (hours > 0.5)
{
    Time = Math.round(hours) + " : " + Math.round(minutes) + " : "  
    +   Math.round(seconds);
}
else
{
    Time = Math.round(minutes) + " : " + Math.round(seconds);
}
return Time;
```

It doesn't give an error, but my problem is some songs return `0` at `.getDuration().toSeconds()`, and other songs return their value perfectly fine. What could cause this problem?

**EDIT:**
In debug mode a song contains `136280.816326` millis.. while `System.out.println(time)` returns 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/McyLD.jpg -- difference between debug and normal build

Comment: Assuming you are using MP3: Duration of VBR (variable bit rate) encoded songs is hard to calculate. Check whether your songs are CBR or VBR

Comment: What library does the `Media` class come from?

Comment: @Dio F Windows explorer says 128kbps, VLC says input varies around 126 to -129 kbps

Comment: Then it's probably VBR. I am not an expert for this. My only advice would be to check different libraries, like [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), which may give better results.

Comment: If I run debugger it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced Problems with this too. After Creating the Media Object it needs some time to get fully initialized (my experience).

You can tryto call your getTime-Method in MediaPlayer's onReady or onPlaying methods.

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I did a `thread.sleep(1000)`, so it could load, then it worked!